Touchlab Xcode-plugin is not working with complex KMP Project
I've got a huge KMP project. min version iOS 14, xCode 15.2
For debugging purpose Kotlin code injected as a local pod: as a src not a binary file. Pod named KotlinShared.
Unfortunately this plugin doesn't work: breakpoints became disabled after build process started.
I've tried to make proj folder struct, as same as at example where breakpoints works perfectly, but I failed, case too much dependencies in this code. Also i've tried to fix it with this answer with same result.
I've got two hypotheses problem in pod compile settings or in different folder struct.
I am not good at LLDB or compile or how xCode work internally but i think i should deep dive here.
So I will appreciated any ideas how i can fix it, or what i should learn in LLDB to fix it by my self or whatever what could help me

You have a better chance of fixing the problem if you report it to the plugin maintainers with a minimal reproducible example.

Good idea, I will try, thanks. Actually i've tried few times but without any resultsю

Some questions. Is the code you're trying to debug the main code of the project or a dependency? I assume it's the main code. If so, are you using the standard local cocoapods build? Are you running a debug build or release? (I'm one of the maintainers, BTW). I would agree that a repro would be great. Also, ping on slack after you reply. I rarely check SO notifications.

One important note. The plugin won't be impacted by "code size". The Kotlin compiler outputs debug info, and all the "plugin" does is point Xcode at lldb transform code. Most of the internals are either Kotlin or lldb. For how lldb works, the debug info has absolute paths to your files, so assuming the kt files are in the same place where you actually compiled them, lldb should find them, and Xcode should not disable breakpoints. When breakpoints disable that's Xcode's way of saying "this isn't debuggable".

BTW, version 2.0 of the plugin is coming out, probably today (although we have that and a major post series both ready to go today, so "marketing" will probably be the tie-breaker). But, in any case, this week. I think it's already released, so you can just upgrade with homebrew. The new version is much faster, and you can see Kotlin vals while debugging from Swift, plus other improvements.

Released: https://touchlab.co/xcode-kotlin-2-0

@KevinGalligan Hey, thanks for you'r reply) I've installed 2.0 but i've got no result :-( So  I'am trying  to prepare demo project now, it takes some time. I'll try to find you in slack. T

After long research I find that issue with breakpoints reproduced only with emulator and related with [support arm64 for iOS Simulators][1]
[1]: https://medium.com/fusionui/from-fat-frameworks-to-xcframeworks-or-how-to-support-arm64-for-ios-simulators-a53f9f097f83
So the issue was produced because path to dSyM files were changed.
